# Custom Button Not Opening as a Primary Tab in Service Console

Tags: custom-button, service-cloud-console

I have created a custom list button on Contacts that can be redirected to a specific record type.
I want the Contacts to be open in a new tab.

```
if (typeof(srcSelf) == 'function') { 
     srcUp("/003/e?RecordType=012F0000001EvIo&accid={!Account.Id}&ent=Contact&retURL=/{!Account.Id}","_blank"); 
}else{ 
     window.open("/003/e?RecordType=012F0000001EvIo&accid={!Account.Id}&ent=Contact&retURL=/{!Account.Id}","_blank"); 
}
```

with this I am able to open Contact as a Sub Tab, but not as a Primary Tab.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
if (typeof(srcSelf) == 'function'){
    srcUp("/003/e?RecordType=012F0000001EvIo&accid={!Account.Id}&ent=Contact&retURL=/{!Account.Id}","_blank"); 
 }else{
    if(sforce.console.isInConsole()){
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,'/003/e?RecordType=012F0000001EvIo&accid=' + '{!Account.Id}' + '&ent=Contact&retURL=/' + '{!Account.Id}', true);
    }
}
```